# Systemd, mount disk before and umount after execution of a service

Tags: systemd, mount, services

What is the best way to do this with systemd?

- mount a partition of an internal hard disk
- execute a service that writes to that partition, preventing umount and shutdown and suspension of the system
- umount the partition after the execution of the service
- (optionally spin down the hard disk)